# How can I update user's position quickly on Google Map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, position

I am working on an app recently, and I need to show user's position on the Google Map.

According to the material I found on the internet and with the help of API.
Now I can show the phone's position and mark it.

Currently I use the code below to obtain the location

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000,0, this);
........
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location!=null){
        currentLocation = location;

        GeoPoint geo = new GeoPoint(((int)location.getLatitude()*1E6),
                 ((int)location.getLongitude()*1E6))
        System.err.println("onLocationChanged"+geo.toString());
        mapController.animateTo(geo);
 }
```

I guess this method would call the`onLocationChanged(Location location)` method every second?

It turns out, the location is detected every 15 sec. But I need to update the location information ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`GPS_PROVIDER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER)

Comment: How did you verify this? If you put debug logs in `onLocationChanged()` you will see a new location every second. I hope you are not calling `removeUpdates()`

Comment: Sorry,didn't give you a prompt reply. I do use the `requestLocationUpdates()` and I put a log on it. I put the log in the  `onLocationChanged()` method, so if it's invoked, I would see it.And it shows a new location approximately every 50 seconds,(which I said in the question 15, that was a mistake, it was 50 as well ).But what I want, is the same work like Google Map App, shows your location immediately as you moves, Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe the first time, it is ok to take 50 seconds to get a fix, but after you get your first location, `onLocationChanged()` must be called every second, as per your code

Comment: you mean I should put `requestLocationUpdates()` in the `onLocationChanged()`?

Comment: No, what I mean is after calling `requestLocationUpdates()`, `onLocationChanged()` will be called after 15 seconds to 1 minute (for the 1st time only). After this first fix, you should get fixes after every second. If possible test this on another device, because there is no problem with your code.

Comment: OK, I will try to find another device. Thanks for your patience!